# Set up my server to allow remote users to connect to my Java program

Tags: java, dns, ip, rmi

My program is a game that uses RMI to allow users to connect to the central server.  The game works fine on computers within my home network.  I want remote users outside of my network to be able to connect to the server.

Based on a similar thread's recommendation I set up a no-ip.com account to map a domain to my game-server so that my computer is publicly accessible.

I changed my code to get a class stub From:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("10.10.10.105"); 
/* 10.10.10.105 is my local address and this works fine on my home network */
```

To:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("mychosenhostname.no-ip.org");  
/* mychosenhostname.no-ip.org is the redirecting domain that I received from no-ip */
```

However this new code gets a `java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:` error.  I used the port checker tool on canyouseeme.org and found that my port 1099 is open.  I'm not sure what else I need to do in order to make my program accessible.

BTW: I am using NetBeans IDE with Glassfish

Comment: Is your NAT router configured to forward requests to your internal machine?

Comment: No I don't think so.  I'm pretty new to the concept of routing so I'm unfamiliar with this concept.  Can you explain a little or direct me to a good resource?  I have a LinkSys WRT54G router and a Windstream cable modem, both of which I can connect to and edit settings.  Edit: Are you talking about port forwarding?  In which case yes I forwarded the port 1099 to the relevant machine.

Comment: Haha, wow, ask and ye shall receive: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/ -- ignore everything on the page except the screenshots. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I believe I have set the ports up correctly.  I have ports 80, 443, 4125, and 1099 open on my firewall and modem and forwarded to my server machine through my router.

Comment: Does `mychosenhostname.no-ip.org` resolve to the correct IP address on the client machine? Can you `telnet mychosenhostname.no-ip.org 1099` or `nc mychosenhostname.no-ip.org 1099` from the client machine to ensure that it can traverse your NAT?

Comment: The host name resolves to my IP address (the same one that shows on www.whatismyip.com).  However I can not telnet it.  Not only that, but I can not "telnet localhost 25" or any other port I can think of.

Comment: Are you doing your testing on your _internal_ network? Or a machine located outside your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer to my problem.  My setup looked like ADSL Modem -> Router -> Machines.

Even though I had the ports forwarded from my DSL modem to the Router and then to the Machines, the DSL modem was completely ignoring its port forwarding settings.  Once I set the DSL Modem in bridge mode and allowed just the router to handle the port forwarding it seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the software firewall on your server.  (If you haven't already ...)
2. Check the ports on the machine you are trying to connect *from*, and its firewall, router, etc.
3. If you are *absolutely sure* that you've got everything right, contact your ISP and ask if *they* are blocking the port.

Comment: Is the problem that my operating system is XP home edition?  The no-ip.com site didn't say anything about needing a server operating system for it to work, but maybe my operating system does not allow for what I am attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Although opening up port 1099 is a good start, that just allows you to contact the RMI **registry**. The actual RMI exported objects will be available on a different port (by default an arbitrary port).

You have two options:

1)  Set up your server in your router as the DMZ (meaning all incoming connections will get routed to that server). Be careful about security on your server though.

2)  Set up specific ports for your object - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html#firewallIn.

PS - a packet capture tool such as Wireshark often helps diagnose these sorts of problems.

Comment: If the OP uses `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` he can use port 1099 for everything.